# awesome wm launch bar widget doesn't appear?

Tags: lua, launch, awesome-wm

From the [wiki](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quick_launch_bar_widget), I only change the shortcut folder to `/home/quanta/.config/awesome/launchbar/` which contains one testing file with content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox
Exec=firefox
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/firefox.png
Position=1
```

This widget is added to wibox by 2 ways:

```lua
mywibox[s].widgets = {
    --memwidget,
    --cpuwidget,
    {
        mylauncher,
        mytaglist[s],
        mypromptbox[s],
        layout = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.leftright
    },
    mylayoutbox[s],
    volume_widget,
    mytextclock,
    s == 1 and mysystray or nil,
    mytasklist[s],
    launchbar,
    layout = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.rightleft
}
```

or:

```
s == 1 and launchbar or nil,
```

but nothing happens after restarting awesome. The configuration file syntax is OK. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try it again - there was a time when the widget posted on the wiki was not working. Anyway, feel free to mail me if it still goes awry.

Answer (score 0):

What version of awesome are you using? If you are using awesome version 3.5, you are looking at the wrong page in the wiki. The like you provided is for awesome 3.4x. Try this updated link:http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quick_launch_bar_widget/3.5

If that doesn't work you, can always use a widget launcher. Here what I have,

```
firefox_launcher     = awful.widget.launcher({ image = "/home/joshua/.config/awesome/icons/Faenza/apps/48/firefox.png",
                       command = "firefox" })


   right_layout:add(firefox_launcher)
```